# ADB used to connect wirelessly, now I can't connect and get double port error (unable to connect *.*.*.*:5555:5555)

Tags: android, adb, wireless

I was using the adb wireless app on my older Droid X. It was working flawlessly for months, no problem at all. I didn't update anything, nothing has changed on anything. The computer wasn't restarted, nor was the phone. Now I can't connect. The following results:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.19:5555
unable to connect to 192.168.1.19:5555:5555
```

So I try:

```
adb kill-server
adb tcpip 5555
```

Which results in:

```
* daemon not running, starting it now on port 5307 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found
```

Restart the computer, restart the phone, same results. Like I say, it happened out of nowhere. Nothing was updated, nothing was changed. Phone and computer were left on, came and tried to connect again after working on it yesterday and no luck. Phone is rooted, and again there were 0 problems prior to today. I can connect via usb using:

```
adb disconnect
adb usb
```

Then "/adb devices" shows my phone. But still can't connect via wireless.

Comment: use some other port instead 5555 here check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930050/adb-connection-over-tcp-not-working-now

Comment: I normally have even ports, starting from 5554 (then 5556, 5558, ...) on my emulated devices

Answer (score 0):

You have put port twice.

If you check the error you can see it : unable to connect to 192.168.1.19:5555:5555

Remove port from the Ip address and leave as it is the command adb tcpip 5555