# Connection refused: ADB connection from Iphone to windows

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

I am trying to build a watch face for Android wear. The Android wear is an emulator and the device that I have is an iPhone connected via USB to my windows laptop

I have followed the instructions from the below link

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html , 
verified device compatibility as per 
https://www.android.com/wear/check/
and have also followed responses as per the answers @ [adb connection over tcp not working now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930050/adb-connection-over-tcp-not-working-now), however I am receiving the following error

**unable to connect to :5555: cannot connect :5555: No conn
ection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)**

Comment: on an android device, this happens when you are not on the same network

Comment: @user3802077, I am using an IPhone, however I have made sure that my device and laptop are on the same wi-fi n/w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I was able to figure out with some research that getting to have iPhone with a wearable emulator may not be possible and decided to have both my device and wearable as emulators. Though it was difficult, I was able to get both my emulators talk to each other with the below link  [Pairing Android and Wear emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205888/pairing-android-and-wear-emulators/25506889#25506889) and https://kennethmascarenhas.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/developing-for-android-wear-with-emulators/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=a97f04efe2-Android_Weekly_116&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-a97f04efe2-337259209 with a minor change to authentication, which I have included as comment in the stackoverflow post

Answer (score 1):

[Actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695442/5832311) means that the host sent a reset instead of an ack when you tried to connect. It is therefore not a problem in your code. Either there is a firewall blocking the connection or the process that is hosting the service is not listening on that port. You may also want to check these SO posts: [Trouble debugging android wear over bluetooth - Unable to connect to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656967/trouble-debugging-android-wear-over-bluetooth-unable-to-connect-to-localhost) and [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it) which also stated that  the machine exists but that it has no services listening on the specified port, or there is a firewall stopping you. You may [check](https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/connection-refused-f58.html) it out.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure out with some research that getting to have iPhone with a wearable emulator may not be possible and decided to have both my device and wearable as emulators.