# Flutter : Not able to open the app on a physical device

Tags: flutter, usb, device

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TKSj.jpg)I have connected my USB device with developers options ON and USB debugging enabled but this is running for the last 20 mins and not opening the app on a physical device.

I tried running it many times but App is not Opening.

Answer (score 0):

you can connect both mobile and ur dev PC into same wifi(Same IP).
and follow this link [adb connection over tcp not working now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930050/adb-connection-over-tcp-not-working-now)